# lucene 5.3 how to add date to your fields

Tags: java, lucene

In previous version of lucene, one could do this:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("file_modified",
DateTools.timeToString(file.lastModified(), DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE),
Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

and store the date for which a file was modified (so later you can search by the date). At the moment, I'm using lucene 5.3 and couldn't figure it out how to do the same? The above code is deprecated (no more `new Field` nor `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED)`

Comment: Use [StringField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html), see the [4.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html)

Comment: @femtoRgon thanks, very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result for this is using [LongField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongField.html) example to solve the problem:

```
            long modified = file.lastModified();
            doc.add(new LongField(FILE_MODIFIED, modified, Field.Store.YES));
```